# java.sql.SQLException: result row count is large threshold

Tags: java, mysql

I am using java and oracle.

[sqlException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEc1i.png)

```
public List<Map<String, String>> TWrongData()throws Exception{
    Statement mStmt=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        mStmt = this.conn.createStatement();
        StringBuffer sbSql= new StringBuffer();
           sbSql.append( " SELECT NB,DA,S,T " );
           sbSql.append( " FROM YS_DBA01_QX WHERE T is null AND S<>0 " );
           rs=mStmt.executeQuery(sbSql.toString());
           ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
           while(rs.next()){
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("NB",rs.getString("NB"));
                String RQ=CommonUtils.DateFormat(rs.getDate("DA"));
                map.put("DA",DA);
                list.add(map);
            }
            return list;
            }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            JDBResourceKit.release(rs);
            JDBResourceKit.release(mStmt);
        }
        return null;
```

---

```
 SELECT JH,RQ,CYFS,PL  FROM YS_DBA01_QX WHERE PL is null AND SCSJ<>0 execute time:31
java.sql.SQLException: result row count is large threshold[100000] sql: SELECT JH,RQ,CYFS,PL  FROM YS_DBA01_QX WHERE PL is null AND SCSJ<>0 
     at com.efounder.sql.EAIResultSet.next(EAIResultSet.java:550)
     at com.zyof.server.xypc.djj.JPLService.PLWrongData(JPLService.java:67)
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help you achieve what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more than 100000 records.
Try to set some limit like:

```
SELECT * FROM XXX LIMIT 5000
```